# Adding variable containing string to array does not work

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

Being very new to bash and unix I'm once again struggling with a very basic issue, i.e. adding a string to an array. What I'm trying to achieve, is to have an array of file names matching a certain pattern. Here's my script:

```
declare -a TASKS=()
find /cs/srpresul/app/deploy/config/imas-config/rdx-tasks-prepared/ -name 
"IMAS-Loaders-*.json"|while read fname; do
   FILE_NAME=$(echo $fname | cut -d'/' -f11)
   echo "$FILE_NAME"
   TASKS+=("$FILE_NAME")
done
TASKS+=('foo' 'bar')
for TASK in "${TASKS[@]}"
do
   echo "$TASK"
   echo "Starting back population for type $TASK between $1 and $2"
done
```

So the result is as follows: the FILE_NAME variable holds proper value, as it is printed correctly, but the TASKS array does not contain them. Only 'foo' and 'bar' values are present in the array. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a pipe so you are appending to `TASKS` in a subshell that is why it does not work. You can use the following:

```
declare -a TASKS=()
for fname in $(find /cs/srpresul/app/deploy/config/imas-config/rdx-tasks-prepared/ -name 
"IMAS-Loaders-*.json"); do
   FILE_NAME=$(echo $fname | cut -d'/' -f11)
   echo "$FILE_NAME"
   TASKS+=("$FILE_NAME")
done
TASKS+=('foo' 'bar')
for TASK in "${TASKS[@]}"
do
   echo "$TASK"
   echo "Starting back population for type $TASK between $1 and $2"
done
```